# How to call to a webservice using background thread in Appdelegate

Tags: ios, web-services, appdelegate

I want to call to my webservice login function within my application `Appdelegate`. If only login is success user should be directed to my `Homeviewcontroller`. If it is not success should be redirect to another viewcontroller. My problem is when I try to call the `webservice` within my `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it is crashing because of blocking the main thread. How I can call this method inside a background service. I dont have any idea about threads in ios. Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do this is load a splash screen from your AppDelegate and then do your launch tasks while the splash screen is displaying. On completion of your launch tasks you then load the appropriate view. You don't need to call your web service on a background thread as NSURLConnection can be called asynchronously (or you can use AFNetworking). There are tons of examples of using NSURLConnection asynchronously on Stackoverflow.